# Ubuntu hangs while working on Google Chrome?

Tags: 14.04

Sir,

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 inside windows with 2Gb RAM.
I am using google chrome alongwith Ubuntu 14.04. If I pause my work for some time and when i come back to work everything will be hangs chrome, cursor, nothing will work. then I have to press power button. 
It hangs by chrome or any other 3rd party software. 
Please solve this issue as soon as possible.

Thank You.

Comment: Is it a wubi installation? Or Virtualbox?

Answer (score 0):

Install Chromium if you must need that a Chrome derivative. I would rather have another browser try the Seamonkey suite. It has a browser (firefox), email client (thunderbird) and IRC client.

I recently saw a Windows XP computer and it was very slow. I uninstalled Chrome and suddenly it became very fast. The problem with Chrome is that it runs multiple processes rather than process threads. Some of these process are always calling home all the time.

With a memory-limited computer like that you need a more lightweight browser.

Comment: Now i am using Chromium instead of Chrome and It's working so fast as compare to Chrome.Thank you so much. It's working faster :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox might work a little bit better than Chrome. If that doesn't work, try QupZilla web browser from the default Ubuntu repositories. QupZilla is  lightweight, very fast and feature-rich, like a scaled-down version of Firefox. You can import your bookmarks from other web browsers into QupZilla.

QupZilla has renamed itself as Falkon and be installed by the following command in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu:

```
sudo snap install falkon
```

Comment: Thank you for suggest me. Firefox is working faster than Chrome but I have to work with Chrome due to some development issues. So now i am using Chromium and it's really good....!!